# Save data to a hosted .dat File

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am saving Data into a .dat file using this Piece of Code:

```
void saveFile () {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("File.dat", true);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (fos);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][0]);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][1]);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][2]);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][3]);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][4]);
        dos.writeUTF (saves[count][5]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "The Record has been Saved Successfully",
                    "Record Saved", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        txtClear ();
        dos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "There are Some Problem with File",
                    "Problem", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

I need to have the .dat File Hosted on some Online Domain Say http://Domain.com/File.dat
What would I need to do to the Piece of code In Order to be able to Accomplish the Save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Either the "domain" is managed on the same server, then you just put the file at the correct place (usually under 'www' folder, check your web server configuration)

2- It's another computer, then you'll have to transfer the file there (FTP? Another Java piece of code using sockets? API given by the host? ...)

---

Unrelated but you should `close` your `Streams` in a `finally` block

```
xxxxxxxStream s = null;
try {
  s = new xxxxxxxStream();
} catch (WhateverException we) {
  ...
} finally {
  s.close();
}
```

Comment: Say I have Already FTP ed the file there, How do I define the Path to save the file in My Code?

Comment: You won't be able to do that simply, you'll need an API like http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html for example